# How to use command line params while running npm for 2 scripts

Tags: node.js, npm

I have the following scripts in the package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "test" : "npm run module1 || npm run posttest",
   "createenv": "node cliTest.js && npm run test"
}
```

cliTest.js has the following:

```
console.log(process.argv);
```

I need to run createenv first to create an env file that will be used by the script 'test'. The problem is that the arguments in the CLI are not made available.

So, if I run the following:

```
npm run createenv foobar
```

I get the following and I do not see 'foobar'

```
[
  '/Users/xxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node',
  '/Users/xxxxx/Documents/core/cliTest.js'
]
```

How can I retrieve the value foobar from the CLI in my cliTest.js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need this &&-chain you can try `npm_config_`, something like this:

```
"createenv": "node cliTest.js ${npm_config_name} && npm run test"
```

then run the command:

```
npm run createenv --name=foobar
```

the last argument in `console.log` should be `foobar`.